# I want to fire an server-sent-event on the node.js server just once when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, server-sent-events

I want to make an process like this :

1. an user select a combo-box menu, and click the 'submit' button.
2. a router on node.js server routes the request from the client.

   what the router does :

   1. get the information from the client
   2. query the data base and get the data.
   3. send an 'draw_chart' event stream to the client html page with the data.
   4. so the function on the page is fired using the data from server.

So I made a form on the client html page source like this

chart.html:

```
<form action = "http://localhost:1337/draw_chart" method = "GET">

                <select id = "xAxisList" name = "xAxisList"></select>

                <select id = "yAxisList" name = "yAxisList"></select>

                <input type = "submit" id = "create_chart">Click to Draw a Chart</input>
</form>
```

and made an router using express module to route the request from the client on the node.js server.

server.js :

```
function draw_chart_handler(req,res){
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
});

    var x = req.body.xAxisList; // get the name of x-axis from the form
    var y = req.body.yAxisList; // get the name of y-axis from the form

    // the three lines below is using external modules.
    chart_generator.setX(x);
    chart_generator.setY(y);
    var d = chart_generator.generateChartData(); 
    // get the data from the data base and manufacture the data for generating chart.

    var data = "event: draw_chart\n" + "data: ";
    data += JSON.stringify(d) + "\n\n";

    res.write(data);
    res.end();
}

app.get('/draw_chart',draw_chart_handler)
```

And they work totally seperately....

The event keeps occurring, even though i never clicked the button,

and when i click the button, the new page comes up with the 'data' on the page,

which is sent from the server by the method 'res.write(data);'....

I don't want to escape the original page.... :(

I think I'm not understanding the event-stream ....

I've searching many websites for node.js studying but I couldn't find out the answer.

How can I make an server-sent-event just once when a button is clicked delivering the data between client and server without escaping the page..??